# Microservice: How to compile eShopOnContainer project

Tags: azure, .net-core, microservices, .net-core-2.1

I tried to compile the project eShopOnContainer. I have heaps of error when I compiled it. I have installed the docker and signup a free trial on their website.

I also installed a

> .NET Core 2.1 SDK (v2.1.300-preview2) - Windows x64 Installer

I ended up having these error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    WebHost.Customization   C:\Users\klam0\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs    2   Active 

Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. Ordering.BackgroundTasks    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135 
Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. WebMVC  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135 
Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. WebSPA  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135 
Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. Ordering.SignalrHub C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135 
Error       The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. FunctionalTests C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135
```

(Above error was trimmed to miminal).

I don't know  is it the last part of the error which cause the error.

> The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. Web.Shopping.HttpAggregator C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets 135

Comment: Have you pulled the latest code from github repo `https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers` dev branch? As per the repo, the code is updated for .NET Core 2.0 and 2.1

Comment: I am sure that I download the latest version from https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8743 Is your Visual Studio 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: It was a 32bit, it is under Program Files(x86) folder.

Comment: Since your Visual Studio is 32 bit you need to install .NET Core 2.2 SDK 32 bit

Comment: i will have a look thanks